# Detect body/face and remove background

Tags: image-processing

My client requested this, and since we don't have any experience of image processing algorithms (and have no interest in diving deep into it either), i thought i'd see if there is anything done before like this. Maybe a framework or something like that.

What they want is that the user takes a photo of themselves, then anything in the picture but themself is replaced with a background image. So they simply can create an image of themself in Bahamas or such.

We can assume that there would only be one person in each picture. What we want is pretty much  a "function" that takes an image, and returns a mask of where the person is in the image. I been searching Google for answers, and i find a lot of face recognition frameworks, but all of them is just for actually detecting a face and giving the position of it. Not masking out the entire person.

Language? Client-side or server-side? Pretty much anything that would work.

Comment: I would recommend not doing the client request in this case, since you have no interest in knowing what you are using and this is a crucial step in Image Processing. Said that, Viola-Jones is a common approach for face detection. Fully automated body detection is usually much more complicated, unapproachable for someone uninterested in the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is a VERY tough problem. Given that the background can be noisy and or complex, even blending in with the person. Of course - upon adding the constraints that the background be a flat, single color and that the images are evenly lit you can use [Chroma keying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key).

Answer (score 0):

On my Nexus, there's a function for the camera that does what you are looking for.

The way it seems to do this is that it first takes an image of the user not on screen and saves that. It then begins capturing again, and any pixels that are unchanged are replaced by the new chosen background. Any pixels that are different are assumed to be the person and are kept as they are in the new capture.

This is similar to chroma keying as anathonline pointed out but rahter than replacing all green pixels with the desired background, you replace all the pixels that remain unchanged with the desired background.

Comment: This is called background subtraction, which, save few cases, produces horrible results for the given application.

Comment: Yeah, but it's fairly simple to employ, and can work in more cases than chrom keying. If the camera stays steady, it will be able to produce reasonable results. In the end, it's all about what the client is willing to accept to get close to what they want.

Comment: It is not only camera that needs to stay steady, the whole environment needs to freeze. You can't ask nature as a whole to freeze, so you have at least minor illumination changes, which might introduce shadows, and other issues.

Comment: I think you should be able to overcome minor changes in the environment. You can do something as simple as add threshold values. You'd have the same shadowing problem with greenscreen, and that's not considered a problem. For small motion changes, for example in wind through tress moving leaves, you can try take average positions and compare those tot he original image (or take several base images to compare with). Then you can ignore everything but major deltas.

Comment: You are simplifying things too much, that has no chance to actually overcome the shortcomings in an open environment. Chroma keying works simply because it is usually applied in very controlled situations, with basically perfect conditions. Now, even under the same conditions, simple background subtraction may fail because when the subject takes place in the scene, it changes the earlier background obtained (you can apply heuristics here, but they are heuristics).